# Haskell: Type safety with logically different Boolean values

Tags: haskell, types, casting, type-safety

Lets say I've got the following code

```
type IsTall = Bool
type IsAlive = Bool

is_short_alive_person is_tall is_alive = (not is_tall) && is_alive
```

Say, later on, I've got the following

```
a :: IsAlive
a = False

b :: IsTall
b = True
```

And call the following, getting the two arguments around the wrong way:

```
is_short_alive_person a b
```

This successfully compiles unfortunately, and at runtime tall dead people are instead found instead of short alive people.

I would like the above example not to compile.

My first attempt was:

```
newtype IsAlive = IsAlive Bool
newtype IsTall = IsTall Bool
```

But then I can't do something like.

```
switch_height :: IsTall -> IsTall
switch_height h = not h
```

As `not` is not defined on `IsTall`s, only `Bool`s.

I could explicitly extract the `Bool`s all the time, but that largely defeats the purpose.

Basically, I want `IsTall`s to interact with other `IsTall`s, just like they're `Bool`s, except they won't interact with `Bool`s and `IsAlive`s without an explicit cast.

What's the best way to achieve this.

---

p.s. I think I've achieved this with numbers by doing in GHC:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype UserID = UserID Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Num)
newtype GroupID = GroupID Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Num)
```

(i.e. UserID's and GroupID's shouldn't interact)

but I can't seem to do this with `Bool`s (deriving Bool doesn't work). I'm not even sure the above is the best approach anyway.

Comment: Your desired `IsTall` and `IsAlive` types are a terrible idea. It's a false generalization of the usually decent idea of using disjoint types to ensure type safety.  Compare this to your `UserID` and `GroupID`; in that case it makes sense to have separate types because it doesn't make sense to pass a `UserId` where a `GroupID` is needed, or add one to the other (though probably neither should implement `Num`).  However, it does make sense to test whether a person is tall *and* alive, tall *or* alive, *not* tall *and* alive, etc.

Comment: sacundim: To a large extent I changed my mind to this point of view. I ended up using things like `newtype Height = Tall | Short` and then doing `x == Tall` etc. A bit more typing, but I thought it made the code more readable and typesafe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get some way towards this, using `newtype`s and a class if you import the Prelude hiding the boolean functions you want to use with your `IsTall` and `IsAlive` values. You redefine the boolean functions as methods in the class, for which you then make instances for all 3 of the `Bool`, `IsTall`, and `IsAlive` types. If you use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` you can even get the `IsTall` and `IsAlive` instances without having to write the wrapping/unwrapping boilerplate by hand.

Here's an example script I actually tried out in ghci:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Prelude hiding ((&&), (||), not)
import qualified Prelude

class Boolish a where
    (&&) :: a -> a -> a
    (||) :: a -> a -> a
    not :: a -> a

instance Boolish Bool where
    (&&) = (Prelude.&&)
    (||) = (Prelude.||)
    not = Prelude.not

newtype IsTall = IsTall Bool
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Boolish)

newtype IsAlive = IsAlive Bool
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Boolish)
```

You can now `&&`, `||`, and `not` values of any of the three types, but not together. And they're separate types, so your function signatures can now restrict which of the 3 they want to accept.

Higher order functions defined in other modules will work fine with this, as in:

```
*Main> map not [IsTall True, IsTall False]
[IsTall False,IsTall True]
```

But you won't be able to pass an `IsTall` to any other function defined elsewhere that expects a `Bool`, because the other module will still be using the Prelude version of the boolean functions. Language constructs like `if ... then ... else ...` will still be a problem too (although a comment by hammar on Norman Ramsey's answer says you can fix this with another GHC extension). I'd probably add a `toBool` method to that class to help uniformly convert back to regular `Bool`s to help mitigate such problems.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cond is useful if you want to take this approach.

Answer (score 11):

If you change your data type slightly you can make it an instance of Functor and you can then use fmap to do operations on the Boolean

```
import Control.Applicative

newtype IsAliveBase a = IsAlive a 
newtype IsTallBase a = IsTall a 

type IsAlive = IsAliveBase Bool
type IsTall = IsTallBase Bool

instance Functor IsAliveBase where
    fmap f (IsAlive b) = IsAlive (f b)

instance Functor IsTallBase where
    fmap f (IsTall b) = IsTall (f b)

switch_height :: IsTall -> IsTall 
switch_height h = not <$> h -- or fmap not h
```

-- EDIT

for operations like && you can make it an instance of Applicative

```
instance Applicative IsAliveBase where
    pure = IsAlive
    (IsAlive f) <*> (IsAlive x) = IsAlive (f x)
```

and then you can do (&&) using liftA2

example:

```
*Main> let h = IsAlive True
*Main> liftA2 (&&) h h 
IsAlive True
```

you can read more about this at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors

Comment: Updated the answer with an example for &&

Answer (score 9):

Your options are either to define algebraic data types like

```
data Height = Tall | Short
data Wiggliness = Alive | Dead
```

or to define new operators, e.g., `&&&`, `|||`, `complement` and to overload them on the type of your choice.  But even with overloading you won't be able to use them with `if`.

I'm not sure that Boolean operations on height make sense anyway. How do you justify a conclusion that "tall and short equals short" but "tall or short equals tall"?

I suggest you look for different names for your connectives, which you can then overload.

P.S. Haskell is always getting new features, so the best I can say is that if you can overload `if` I'm not aware of it.  To say about Haskell that "such-and-such can't be done" is always dangerous...

Comment: You can overload `if` using the `RebindableSyntax` extension in recent versions of GHC. [Quick example](https://gist.github.com/2657492).

Comment: @Norman: I tried Ben's answer, which worked fairly well, but in the end I decided it was cleaner to just define Enums as you suggested. I realised I could do what I was doing largely without logical operations.